# vba function I wanted to port over to libreoffice

Tags: vba

This function works in excel as is, but when I try to port it to libreoffice it doesn't work (vba standards changed?)

variant() apparently isn't a datatype in openoffice...

but here's my code

```
Public Function RankECDF(ByRef r_values As Range) As Variant()

Dim N As Integer, M As Integer

Dim total As Integer

Dim y() As Variant

N = r_values.Rows.Count
M = r_values.Columns.Count

y = r_values.Value    'copy values from sheet into an array

Dim V() As Variant
ReDim V(1 To N, 1 To M)

    total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r_values)

            For R = 1 To N
                For C = 1 To M

                    If y(R, C) = "" Then

                    V(R, C) = ""

                    Else

                        'would error if cell was ""

                        V(R, C) = WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Rank(y(R, C), r_values, 1), WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r_values, "<=" & y(R, C))) / WorksheetFunction.Count(r_values)

                    End If

                 Next C
            Next R

RankECDF = V

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OpenOffice does not like `Variant()` but that should be fine as `Variant` can anything, even a `Variant()` right?

Under v4.0, plugging your code into OpenOffice's Basic Debugger (**Tools -> Macros -> OrganizeMacros -> OpenOffice Basic...**) and breaking on `N = r_values.Rows.Count` shows the following:

[image]

So it looks like `r_values` is not an `Range` but a `Variant()`.

When I change the code to treat `r_values` as such (using `UBound`) it appears to work. Try this:

```
Public Function RankECDF(ByRef r_values As Range)

Dim N As Integer, M As Integer

Dim total As Integer

Dim y() As Variant

'N = r_values.Rows.Count
'M = r_values.Columns.Count

N = UBound(r_values)
M = UBound(r_values, 2)


y = r_values 

Dim V() As Variant
ReDim V(1 To N, 1 To M)
    total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r_values)
            For R = 1 To N
                For C = 1 To M
                    If y(R, C) = "" Then

                    V(R, C) = ""

                    Else

                        'would error if cell was ""

                        V(R, C) = WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Rank(y(R, C), r_values, 1), WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r_values, "<=" & y(R, C))) / WorksheetFunction.Count(r_values)

                    End If

                 Next C
            Next R

RankECDF = V

End Function
```

Comment: What error do you get when you add the function with the Open Office Basic editor open?

Comment: it was weird, it didn't shout out an error.  I tried setting my macro security to low.  I just get a bunch of cells as output as #Value!... wait, I got a "N = UBound(r_values)" something 'not optional'

Comment: I got a "N = UBound(r_values)" 'argument is not optional'

Comment: Try changing to to `UBound(r_values, 1)`. What version of Open Office are you running?

Comment: 4 (I switch sometimes between libre and open tho)

Comment: same error, same line with the ",1" addition, but now all my values are blanks

Comment: another error when I try to run it on just one value.  I get a bunch of "object variable's not set"